# How to give list object as a field with retrofit?

Tags: android, list, post, retrofit

**Service class**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/suggestie/postdossier")
void postDossier(@Field("vraagId")int vraagId,@Field("tekst") String tekst, @Field("gebruikerId") int gebruikerId, @Field("blokken") List<Blok> blokken, Callback<Dossier> callback);
```

**Application class**

```
  private Service createService(Context context) {
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") 
            .create();

    return new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setEndpoint(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.baseURL))
            .build()
            .create(Service.class);

}
```

**Adapter class**

```
public void postDossier(int vraagId, int gebruikerId) {
    Log.e("size van blokken", Integer.toString(blokken.size()));
    getService().postDossier(vraagId, titelDossier, gebruikerId, blokken, this);
}

@Override
public void success(Dossier dossier, Response response) {
    Log.e("postdossier is gelukt!", "");
    Log.e("id dossier", Integer.toString(dossier.getSuggestieId()));
}

@Override
public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
    Log.e("postdossier gefaald", "");
    StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
    error.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
    Log.e("stacktrace",errors.toString());
}
```

**Blok class**

```
public class Blok {
private String Titel;
private int Soort;
private String Inhoud;
private int Position;

public Blok(int position, String titel, int soort, String inhoud) {
    this.Position = position;
    this.Titel = titel;
    this.Soort = soort;
    this.Inhoud = inhoud;
}

public String getTitel() {
    return Titel;
}

public void setTitel(String titel) {
    this.Titel = titel;
}

public int getSoort() {
    return Soort;
}

public void setSoort(int soort) {
    this.Soort = soort;
}

public String getInhoud() {
    return Inhoud;
}

public void setInhoud(String inhoud) {
    this.Inhoud = inhoud;
}

public int getPosition() {
    return Position;
}

public void setPosition(int position) {
    this.Position = position;
}
```

}

When i post a dossier without any blocks it's ok. But when i have blocks inside the list retrofit returns a internal server error. But me and my team checked the server side and everything is good there.

Do we pass the list the wrong way? I searched through google for hours but i didn't find any answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of retrofit are you using?

Comment: I had same issue in the past, you should just update retrofit lib to newest version

Comment: I have the newest version installed....

Comment: can you show your Block class?

Comment: just for the record: i'm using retrofit 1.9.0, okhttp 2.3.0 and okhttp-urlconnection 2.3.0

Comment: I'm using the same version of retrofit but i don't have depencendies for okhttp and okhttp-urlconnection? Do i need them? I haven't used them for my other get & post methods. And you can see my block class now in the main post.

Comment: @MathisseDeStrooper did you succeed?